# Django Rest Framework APIView no delete and put allowed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on the tutorial on the website of the django rest framework. When i make a PUT or DELETE call to the server the methods for a particular are not allowed. This is my view:

```
class SnippetDetailView(APIView):
    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):        
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        snippet.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

I used the following urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^snippets/', SnippetListView.as_view()),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', SnippetDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

My response header shows the following:

```
Allow → GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
```

I haven't set any restrictions whatsoever. What did I miss which doesn't allow the PUT and DELETE methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For those still struggling with this issue. After hours of moving back and forth I found the solution. The issues was with the url. Old urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^snippets/', SnippetListView.as_view()),
url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', SnippetDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

working urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^snippets/$', SnippetListView.as_view()),
url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', SnippetDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

The difference is minute but the issue was related the trailing slash in the old version which was used to trigger the SnippetDetailView.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In Django 2.*:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)', SnippetDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.